# Javac command prompt compilation classes not found

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

New to java so getting my hands dirty with cmd compilation. Getting 'cannot find symbol' for the instantiated classes. Please please help! :)

MovieDAO class for database query instantiates beans MovieDetails and MovieInfo.

Directory structure: Under root folder for the project, have src\com\library\model containing MovieDAO.java, MovieDetails.java, MovieInfo.java.

MovieDetails and MovieInfo already compiled. The .class files are in classes\com\library\model. This is also the intended directory for the MovieDAO class.

MovieDAO has:

```
package com.library.model;
```

AND

```
import com.library.model.*;
```

Command prompt is at root folder (Project). Entered command:

```
javac -classpath C:\Users\Sudipto\Desktop\.....\mysql-connector-java.jar:classes:. -d classes src\com\library\model\MovieDAO.java
```

Compilation error:

```
....MovieDAO.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails();
^
```

Same with MovieInfo. Obviously some little thing I'm missing. Can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Run javac from src directory and change src\com\library\model.MovieDAO.java to com\library\model\MovieDAO.java.

Ex:
Source Dir: D:\~\JavaSamples\src

Classes Dir: D:\~\JavaSamples\classes

So when you try compiling from src directory as below:

```
D:\~\JavaSamples\src>javac -classpath ../classes -d ../classes com\library\model\MovieDAO.java
```

Comment: Changed directory to src, changed command to: javac -classpath C:\Users\Sudipto\Desktop\.....\mysql-connector-java.jar:classes:. -d classes com\library\model\MovieDAO.java (removed src). Getting error: javac: directory not found: classes. Seems to be taking the 'classes' after -d as the directory. Didn't have this problem from the root folder.

Comment: Sudipto - I have included an example. See that carefully and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `classes` folder is in current directory, because you have included just `:classes:` in classpath.

If `classes` folder is not in current directory, then include either absolute (or) relative path to `classes` folder in classpath. like

```
javac -classpath c:\...\connector.jar:.\classes: -d <target>

(or)

javac -classpath c:\...\connector.jar:c:\project\classes: -d <target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The path separator in Windows is semicolon (;) as opposed to the colon (:) in Unix. Also, there is no need to put the current directory (.) on the class path. If it were me, I'd put the classpath in quotes, just to make sure I don't accidentally reference paths with spaces, but that part is up to you.

If you want java to compile all of the uncompiled source code, add src to the classpath.

```
javac -classpath "C:\Users\Sudipto\Desktop\.....\mysql-connector-java.jar;classes;src" -d classes src\com\library\model\MovieDAO.java
```

Otherwise, if you definitely want to use the already compiled classes and not recompile the source code for `MovieDetails` and `MovieInfo`, just leave off src.

```
javac -classpath "C:\Users\Sudipto\Desktop\.....\mysql-connector-java.jar;classes" -d classes src\com\library\model\MovieDAO.java
```

Finally, if `MovieDao` is in `com.library.model`, there is no need to import `com.library.model.*.`

Comment: Thanks for your response. it's really instructive :). I removed the import in MovieDAO and entered the command you suggested. Compile error: cannot access MovieDetails, class file: classes\com\library\model\MovieDetails.class     class file contains wrong class      Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.  HELP!

Comment: Resolved! Murderously stupid. Didn't include package in the beans. Thanks guys!